# Storing 16Bit Audio on a 8bit byte array in android

Tags: java, android, audio, audio-recording, pcm

I'm confused. I needed to record sound from MIC in Android so I used the following code:

```
recorder = new AudioRecord(AudioSource.MIC, 44100,
                AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,
                AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, N);
buffer = new byte[N];
//...
recorder.read(buffer, 0, N);
```

As we know, a byte array can store values between -128 to +128 while a 16Bit sound needs a lot more storage(e.g. short and int) but surprisingly Java and Android have a `record` method which saves recorded data to a byte array.

How that can be possible? What am I missing?

Comment: *"while a 16Bit sound needs a lot more storage("*  2 bytes.  Not 'a lot' by my definition of 'a lot'.

Comment: "By the time you have a 16-bit sequence, there are 65,536 possible levels"as indicated in this url: [link](http://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/bit-depth) assuming 16666 is a frame value, How 16666 is stored on a byte array?max storable value is 128. Please be nice and help me understand

Comment: *"a 16-bit sequence"*  Can be stored in two bytes.  I don't know how to make it simpler.  OK, try this.  Instead of thinking as a byte having a value of -128 to 128, presume it is 0 to 255.  That is 256 separate values.  With two bytes we can represent any of 256 **x** 256 values, or 65,536 values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are thinking of byte as a shot integer. It is just 8 bits. You need to store 1000111011100000 (16 bits)? First byte is 10001110, second byte is 11100000. That you can interpret these bits as numbers is not relevant here. In a more general way, byte[] is usually how you deal with binary "raw data" (let it be audio streams or encrypted content or anything else that you treat like a stream of bits).

If you have n "words" of 16 bits then you will need 2n bytes to store it. Byte 0 will be lower (or higher) part of word 0, byte 1 will be the rest of word 0, byte 0 will be lower (or higher) part of word 1...

Comment: i get what u r trying to say: "a 16bit audio is composed of 2 bytes."But how can "2 bytes" be stored in a single JAVA Byte array?`byte[] byteArray = new byte[] {87, 79, 87, 46, 46, 46};` byteArray[0] is only one byte not 2 bytes.am i right? in order to store 2bytes we need to double the array size.am i right?

Comment: If you have n "words" of 16 bits then you will need 2n bytes to store it. Byte 0 will be lower (or higher) part of word 0, byte 1 will be the rest of word 0, byte 0 will be lower (or higher) part of word 1...

Comment: Thanks for answering me. Please consider adding ur comment to the answer. so i can mark it as accepted. Are you aware of a book which explains such concepts step by step?